# Will our Beta label be removed?

Tags: discussion

Since we learned that [Matter Modeling is graduating](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/298/5) and [Quantum Computing is graduating](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/517/2293) and [Freelancing is graduating](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340/25010) and [Retrocomputing is graduating](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1065/18437) and [Economics is graduating](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2161/20029), I'm curious if HSM will be too?

Answer (score 5):

In fact, the answer to your question is **YES**! We, the moderators, were recently informed that, on

**December 16th, 2021**,

we will officially lose the Beta label and become a fully-fledged Stack Exchange site.

For the day-to-day functioning of the site, this will not really make a big difference (beyond the removal of the "Beta" label on every page). It does imply, however, that we will have moderator elections sometime in the coming year. We will make sure to keep you, the community, posted on any developments on that front.

Around the 16th of December, a post on Meta Stack Exchange will appear to officially announce our graduation (and that of several other sites) along with some other information, but we've been given the go-ahead to tell you guys already. Thanks to all of our users for contributing to the site and making this possible!

Yay! :D

Comment: That's a wonderful news!

Comment: _"beyond the removal of the "Beta" label on every page"_ — the site should also be able to get a custom icon instead of three letters in a bubble, as well as a logo/background.

Answer (score 3):

Our Beta label has been removed and we are officially a full fledged site! (Yay!) I guess there will be a post by a staff member soon.